# Set a variable from a drop down list to a Java class using a bean

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

What seems to be the problem with this:

```
<jsp:setProperty property="selectedCopyValue" value ="<%=request.getParameter("numCopiesList") %>" name="copyBean"/>
```

I get a HHTP Error Code: 500 that says : Attribute numCopiesList is unrecognised for jsp element jsp:setProperty

So I thought it was because I had double quotes within my double quotes but when I change it to `value ="<%=request.getParameter('numCopiesList') %>"` I'm getting a complier error that says Invalid Character Constant on my numCopiesList.

My numCopiesList is a drop down list `<select name="numCopiesList" >` that has 10 options. I'm just trying to grab the current value that is selected within the box and set it to a variable in a java class using my bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting the value of a parameter, use the syntax `${param.paramName}` instead of `request.getParameter`

```
<jsp:setProperty name="copyBean" property="selectedCopyValue" value="${param.numCopiesList}"/>
```